# How do I modify the position of DOM elements without creating new ones?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some simple HTML that looks like this:

```
<body>
  <form action="#">
    <button type="button" onclick="changeDOM();">Change DOM</button>
  </form>
  <table>
    <tr id='a'><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr id='b'><td>b</td></tr>
    <tr id='c'><td>c</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

I want the `changeDOM` function to push the top row of the table to be the bottom row and 'bubble-up' the rest of the rows. I tried doing it like this:

```
function changeDOM() {
    var nextRow = currentRow.nextSibling;
    currentRow.className='';
    nextRow.nextSibling = currentRow;
    currentRow = nextRow;
    currentRow.className='highlight';
    return true;
}

var currentRow;
currentRow = document.getElementById('a');
currentRow.className='highlight';
```

Unfortunately, as I stepped through the debugger, I noticed that `nextSibling` wasn't getting set as I expected. I've seen some similar code online, but they actually delete nodes and append them. Two questions:

1. **Is there a way to change the position of DOM elements without creating and destroying them?**
2. If the answer to (1) is yes, then **How do I do this?**

Comment: Isn't moving something in the digital world always copy/delete? (unless you're just referencing). Don't you just want what's most efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.removeChild` and `.appendChild` methods do not actually delete or create anything, they simply establish and remove association of the node with its parent. Using those methods you'll do exactly what you want - move element without any overhead.

As MDN documentation on [`.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild) says:

```
var oldChild = element.removeChild(child)
```

> The removed child node
>   still exists in memory, but is no longer part of the DOM. You may
>   reuse the removed node later in your code, via the oldChild object
>   reference.

Actually, since element can have only one parent, using `.appendChild` and all other similar methods will automatically remove it from previous location, so you can move element around without using `.removeChild` at all.

Comment: Cool. Is there an explanation for why my code doesn't work? I think the intent is pretty clear, but I'm at a loss to why assigning a new value to the `.nextSibling` property fails.

Comment: .nextSibling is a read-only property. You should use `.insertBefore` method for this effect.

Comment: As a note to anyone that is curious, if you are looking to reset `currentRow` you must use `currentRow = parentNode.firstElementChild;` NOT `currentRow = parentNode.firstChild;`, @Oleg if you could explain this that would be awesome too, but your answer was plenty helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use jQuery, there is a simple function to do that. You can check the following example:

http://api.jquery.com/detach/